# ¿Se pone coma después de la locución adverbial "a la verdad"?

Tags: gramática, puntuación, locuciones

> **A la verdad,** el hijo del vecino se irá tal como lo anunció.

¿Lleva esa coma tras *a la verdad*?

Answer (score 4):

La Gramática de la RAE contempla las locuciones ‘la verdad’ y ‘a la verdad que’ (30.8.1a) como adverbios de la enunciación y al ejemplificar utiliza coma tras el primero. La Ortografía por su parte enuncia que:

> Como regla general, los complementos circunstanciales pueden aparecer determinados por coma cuando preceden al verbo. La mayoría de estas comas son opcionales, pero su presencia es útil para aclarar la jerarquización de los miembros del enunciado.

Mi conclusión es que sí debes usar coma pero no ‘a’, o utilizar ‘que’ y, por supuesto, entonces la coma no es necesaria.